# Vlookup with if function in VB macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the below in VBA macro.

I want the macro to look for a certain value in Sheet 1 in Excel and perform a `VLOOKUP` with the value in the sheet2 in Excel.

If the value in field in Sheet 1 is blank, Excel should display blank as well instead of `#N/A`.

I'm able to write code for performing the `VLOOKUP`, however I am really not sure of how to put in the `IF` command.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Range("G5:G600").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F5,Sheet2!D:F,3,0)"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: There are at least 50+ answers with similar requests involving `VLookup` here on **SO**. A simple **GOOGLE** would show at least a few of them.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to including the `IF` is to ensure that all double-quotation marks are escaped:

```
.Range("G5:G600").Formula = "=IF(F5="""","""",VLOOKUP(F5,Sheet2!D:F,3,0))"
```